# Implement heightForRowIndexPath: in iOS 7, but remove it in iOS 8 using compile-time macro

Tags: uitableview, ios7, macros, ios8, heightforrowatindexpath

I'd like to implement the new auto-resizing table view cells in iOS 8, while maintaining support for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in iOS 7.  The problem is I have to remove the method override `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for iOS 8, but keep in it for iOS 7.  Is there some compile-time macro to use that will accomplish this?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Here is my solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022113/how-to-override-a-method-only-if-ios-version-earlier-thn-8/26022467#26022467][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022113/how-to-override-a-method-only-if-ios-version-earlier-thn-8/26022467#26022467

Answer (score 3):

You can not use a compile time macro because this is a run time decision. Instead, you can just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for iOS 8 and if not, return your calculated height value.

```
#define IS_IOS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

-(CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView * ) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath * ) indexPath {
  if (IS_IOS_8_OR_LATER)
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  else {
    //Your iOS 7 code here.
  }

}
```