# How to only override a method depending on the runtime system iOS version?

Tags: ios, ios8, tableview, uitableview

I've implemented automatic dynamic tableview cell heights for iOS 8 by using

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

For pre-iOS 8, which does not support automatic dynamic cell heights, I overrided the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

This is a similar to what I did: [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

The problem is to how to write code that uses automatic cell height for iOS 8 but overrides heightForRowAtIndexPath for earlier iOS versions. 
I'd like my custom heightForRowAtIndexPath method only if iOS version is less than 8.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You might also consider just using a different data source in iOS 7 and iOS 8. (i.e. an object of a different class)

Comment: @JesseRusak is absolutely correct, and this is the recommended practice. Create a class cluster for your data source which provides the appropriate concrete implementation at runtime.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One solution would be to override the `respondsToSelector:` method in your view controller. Have it return `NO` under iOS 8 when checking for the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector {
    static BOOL useSelector;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        useSelector = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 8.0 ? YES : NO;
    });

    if (selector == @selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)) {
        return useSelector;
    }

    return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}
```

This way, when the table view make a call like:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
}
```

your code will return `NO` under iOS 8 or later and `YES` under iOS 7 or earlier.

Comment: I added this as a category for `UITableViewController`, so you don't have to add it to every single one. Also you can test if the selector is `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, since I believe that is also not needed for iOS8.

Comment: @Koen It's dangerous to override a method in a category since that is undefined behavior. It may work or it may not.

Comment: Good point, I will remove the category and add this to every `UITableViewController`

Comment: @Koen A better solution is to create your own subclass of `UITableViewController` and add the method there. That have all of your table view controller extend your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution. 
Declared this macro to recognize if user has iOS 8.0 or later:

```
#define IS_IOS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

Then, inside heightForRowAtIndexPath I added the following code:

```
if (IS_IOS_8_OR_LATER) {
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        return self.tableView.rowHeight;
    } else {//Custom code for ios version earlier than 8.0

}
```

This solved the problem

Comment: The downside to this approach is you lose a lot of the performance gain. Since the table sees that you implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, it calls it for every row. My solution gives you back the performance gain.